# Why isn't count nodes working?

Tags: xml, perl, bash, xpath

Sample XML:

```
<test name="1" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:44.361 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:45.361 -0700" elapsed="1" />
<test name="2" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:45.362 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:46.362 -0700" elapsed="1" />
<test name="3" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:46.363 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:53.365 -0700" elapsed="7" />
<test name="4" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:53.365 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:11:39.374 -0700" elapsed="46" />
```

First of all, I tried

```
xpath somefile.xml test
```

And it gave me:

```
<test name="1" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:44.361 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:45.361 -0700" elapsed="1" />-- NODE --
<test name="2" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:45.362 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:46.362 -0700" elapsed="1" />-- NODE --
<test name="3" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:46.363 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:53.365 -0700" elapsed="7" />-- NODE --
<test name="4" result="Passed" starttimestamp="2013-05-07 10:10:53.365 -0700" endtimestamp="2013-05-07 10:11:39.374 -0700" elapsed="46" />-- NODE --
```

Then I want to count all tests that are passed, that is all nodes who has a parameter `"Passed"`. So I used the following xpath expression:

```
xpath somefile.xml count(test[@result="Passed"])
```

However it gives me:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Then I tried

```
xpath somefile.xml test[@result="Passed"]
```

And it said:

> No nodes found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect this is just a matter of `bash` handling your command line arguments in a way other than you were expecting. Try this:

```
xpath somefile.xml 'count(test[@result="Passed"])'
```

That way the whole of your second command-line argument should get through without any special meaning for `(`, `[` etc.